# Find a holomorphic injection $f$

Tags: analysis

Find a holomorphic injection $f$ such that $$f\Big(\{ z\in \mathbb C: |\text{Re}z|<1\}\Big)=\{z\in \mathbb C: \text{Re}z>0, \text{Im}z>0\}$$
and$$f(0)=1+i.$$ *My try:* $$z\mapsto i\cdot z\mapsto z+i$$

However, I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via $z\mapsto iz +i$ you map the strip $S_1:=\{|\Re z|<1\}$ to the strip
$S_2:=\{0<\Im z<2\}$. By multiplication with $\frac \pi 4$ as image you get
$S_3:=\{0<\Im z<\frac \pi 2\}$. Now apply the exponential map to obtain
$Q:=\{\Re z>0, \Im z >0\}$. The composition of these maps is $g(z)= \exp\left ( \frac{\pi} 4i (z+1)\right)$ which sends $0$ to $\frac{\sqrt 2} 2(1+i)$.

Finally multiplying by $\sqrt 2$ you keep $Q$ as image  of the map but you map $0$ to $1+i$:
the final map is $$f(z)=\sqrt{2} \exp\left ( \frac{\pi} 4i (z+1)\right)\,.$$

Note that this map is actually injective, since the "height" of $S_3$ is $\frac \pi 2 <2\pi$, hence the exponential map restricted to it is injective.

Comment: Why $0$ sends to $\frac{\sqrt 2} 2(1+i)=\cos (\frac{\pi}{4})+i\cdot \sin  (\frac{\pi}{4})=e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}$? I get that $0\mapsto e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$

Comment: $ \exp\left ( \frac{\pi} 4i (z+1)\right)_{|z=0}=  \exp\left ( \frac{\pi} 4i \right)=\frac{\sqrt 2} 2(1+i)$.